# How do I edit settings (as text) on VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Almost every extension I've looked at has a list of settings that needs to be added, usually in JSON format... but when you click on the settings cog, it gives you a form to fill in – nowhere to enter JSON.

So where exactly is one supposed to put the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual settings editor is just a fancy UI for the json. When you see a documentation that says something like:

> To use this extension, make sure to set:
>
> ```
> "extension.enableFoo": "bar"
> ```

Just search `extension.enableFoo` in the settings editor and then enter the value `"bar"`.

But if you need to edit the json directly, you can click on the `Open Settings JSON` button in the top right corner:

[image]

Or use the: `Preferences: Open settings (JSON)` command to open the settings as json without first opening the visual settings editor:

[image]